# ggmap() not displaying the map on Rstudio

Tags: r, maps, ggmap

```
map <- get_map(zoom=1)
ggmap(map)
```

Just the beginner code of **ggmap** is not displaying the map in plot.

I have tried updating the packages which also didn't work.

And `print(ggmap(map))` also didn't work.

Comment: You may wanna try with a different zoom number. Ultimately, you would use this function to get a map with a specific location. I would recommend you to read `?get_map`. Type this in your R console.

Comment: Works for me if I use `zoom = 3` or more.